# Converting a likelihood function into R code

Tags: r, math, equation

I am needing to use the following likelihood equation to solve for "r" in a dose response experiment. In this equation, for i = 1,2,.....j, Ni is the number of individuals exposed to dose Di, and Yi the number that became infected.

[image: Maximum likelihood equation]

I have managed to construct the dataframe for Ni, Di and Yi, but as I am new to MLE, I am struggling to convert the equation into R code.

Would anyone be able to assist in the code conversion part?

Thanks

PS. Following the suggestion of Rui Barradas below, here is the dataset the paper which developed the equation used:

```
Di <- c(4.2,8,10.6,11.9,12.2,12.6,13,13.2,28.3,28.7,68.2,69,71.1,83,91.7,95.5,106.5,136.5,171.2,186.9,309.3,1557.1)
Ni <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Yi <- c(0,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Di, Ni, Yi)
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Try `sum(Y * log(1 - exp(-r * D))) - r * sum(D * (N - Y))`.

Comment: Many thanks. I can't believe how easy (and logical) writing the equation in R is! PS. I have added the data to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize for the r parameter with the following code :

```
log_Lik <- function(r, D, N, Y)
{
   return(sum(Y * log(1 - exp(-r * D))) - r * sum(D * (N - Y)))
}

optimise(f = log_Lik, lower = 0, upper = 5, maximum = TRUE, D = D, N = N, Y = Y)
```

Comment: Many thanks Emmanuel! The code worked perfectly and reproduced the solution in the original paper.

Answer (score 1):

Though there already is an accepted answer, here is a different version of the objective function that uses `with` to avoid having to pass the parameters one by one. This is useful since the values of `D`, `N` and `Y` are columns of a data.frame, the df can be passed as one data set.

```r
D <- c(4.2,8,10.6,11.9,12.2,12.6,13,13.2,28.3,28.7,68.2,69,
       71.1,83,91.7,95.5,106.5,136.5,171.2,186.9,309.3,1557.1)
N <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
Y <- c(0,0,1,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(D, N, Y)

loglike <- function(r, data) {
  with(data, 
       sum(Y * log(1 - exp(-r * D))) - r * sum(D * (N - Y))
  )
}

optimize(loglike, lower = 0, upper = 5, maximum = TRUE, data = df)
#> $maximum
#> [1] 0.0425722
#> 
#> $objective
#> [1] -11.75483
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>